# How to install Visual Studio 2010 if Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 is already installed in windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

In my system, Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 is already installed.

Is there any way to install VS2010 on the same system ?

I have windows 7 installed.

Comment: Sure, you can try it. No guarantees it will work properly. The *recommended* course of action is to install the older versions first, working forwards in time. If you want to install VS 2010 *after* VS 2013 and 2015 are already installed, you are taking a risk. Minimize the damage by installing VS 2010 now, then reinstalling VS 2013, and finally reinstalling VS 2015. That should fix anything that the VS 2010 install broke.